# PGP Encrypt using BouncyCastle in Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pgp

I was given a task to build a java method to encrypt data (String or InputStream) using PGP. I have generated a test public key, private key with passphrase following the guide [here](https://edoceo.com/sys/gpg). I then exported the public key using the command below and copy and pasted it to my java code.

```
gpg --armor --output pubkey.txt --export 'Your Name'
```

I am able to encrypt a file using the command below

```
gpg --encrypt --armor -r 'Your Name' plaintext.txt
```

And I get the below content which is what I'm trying to achieve in my java program. I might need to sign it later as part of the requirement but all I want to do for now is to be able to successfully encrypt it like this.

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)

hQEMA0PxXau0Q30VAQf/RuWsN3f4L2HW2GJWOZUjetJsw0odXYbDc7Sug1gZULP8
I0KRrvxnHgiiJgSlBZsws8E8iB1/LDCYJ8oJGj6olicz83iUT8VLdzdJZlc0+96/
BHAvtSTtEv2PWZlh307nU+Zn9cuGAccaijyekCosS5/0JpDyXSFefsLTexMgphAL
veXsxtsISyUU6S0xUux6Ac9HgUWTpCrlNaSdqBN1bk7y8YuvbZgbQ5akwY5FEbq1
f9rxmgXgEgz3N+7f8n5yN2OvWiEyXb+qngVgDLzysD8NTtKDqtw5nViscvVF1h3v
AebdxYxOKGYnWk6XAWhpIgIZdY0ZXG0yu9NJH5VfLtJSAc3c6d2/Nhb7g+k+f2Mn
srZW6XzHCeyGQQqSfr5YJfyUVdsW12udmhnc+ErbRkz84oDkMvFaxes6+2AAKrP/
jdWXsp4fTPl454m+tG5ec/Kn0Q==
=cZH2
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

The java method I need to build accepts a Public Key as a String parameter where I then use the following method to convert it to a PGPPublicKey.

```
  private static PGPPublicKey getPublicKey(String keyAscii) throws IOException, PGPException, Exception {
    InputStream encodedKey = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyAscii.getBytes());
    InputStream decodedKey = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(encodedKey);

    JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection(decodedKey);
    decodedKey.close();

    PGPPublicKey key = null;
    Iterator<PGPPublicKeyRing> rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings();
    while (key == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
      PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = rIt.next();
      Iterator<PGPPublicKey> kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();

      while (key == null && kIt.hasNext()) {
        PGPPublicKey k = kIt.next();

        if (k.isEncryptionKey()) {
          key = k;
        }
      }
    }
    if (key == null) {
      throw new Exception("Can't find key");
    }
    return key;
  }
```

However, when I run the java program, I get an error "exception constructing public key" on the following line of code.

```
      OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(encOut, new byte[4096]);
```

Complete error below

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: exception constructing public key
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator.encryptSessionInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
    at pgp.PgpImpl.encrypt(PgpImpl.java:84)
    at pgp.PgpImpl.main(PgpImpl.java:216)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:83)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:211)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createKeyFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createKeyFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter.implGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I followed the sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826843/java-pgp-encryption-using-bouncy-castle) but it didn't provide any information on how to construct the publickey coming from a String.

Here's my code so far.

```
package pgp;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.KeyFingerPrintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPDataEncryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.jcajce.JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection;

public class PgpImpl {

  public PgpImpl() {
  }

  private static String encrypt(byte[] data, PGPPublicKey encryptionKey) throws Exception {
    String step = "Step-0";
    try {
      step = "Step-1";
      PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
          new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_256)
          .setWithIntegrityPacket(true)
          .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
          .setProvider("BC"));
      
      step = "Step-2";
      encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encryptionKey)
          .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider("BC"));

      step = "Step-3";
      ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      step = "Step-4";
      // create an indefinite length encrypted stream
      OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(encOut, new byte[4096]);
      step = "Step-5";
      // write out the literal data
      PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
      OutputStream pOut = lData.open(cOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE, data.length,
          new Date());
      pOut.write(data);
      pOut.close();
      // finish the encryption
      cOut.close();
      step = "Step-6";
      
      return new String(encOut.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //throw new Exception(String.format("%s: %s", e.getMessage(), step));
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(step);
  }

  private static PGPPublicKey getPublicKey(String keyAscii) throws IOException, PGPException, Exception {
    InputStream encodedKey = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyAscii.getBytes());
    InputStream decodedKey = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(encodedKey);

    JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection(decodedKey);
    decodedKey.close();

    PGPPublicKey key = null;
    Iterator<PGPPublicKeyRing> rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings();
    while (key == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
      PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = rIt.next();
      Iterator<PGPPublicKey> kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();

      while (key == null && kIt.hasNext()) {
        PGPPublicKey k = kIt.next();

        if (k.isEncryptionKey()) {
          key = k;
        }
      }
    }
    if (key == null) {
      throw new Exception("Can't find key");
    }
    return key;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String publicKey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\r\n" + "Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)\r\n"
        + "\r\n" + "mQENBGA1A70BCADK8BnH6GgMbnS1TJSpJvgH+D9VIw0sN8XZWQsUmWWV9WSqhqXt\r\n"
        + "5wNC4XJDcaWtMCapaekQXV5S52T7QCxAz/E5oZzIDe+IUCHQz0WUs37S4Wnw+SZ6\r\n"
        + "QNPXOFaC4nNByRq6gvg0+wtD2Bo/3OJur3f0O0aRSHNiwfd0PdFgG0NU5vGV9PwE\r\n"
        + "xbTMpGssWexIC0MwJaYfJkxzov33CkwLaITvBTCn/J3oeX6JarMkgpurp1FAW0Jk\r\n"
        + "YzgGMOOxwuEVedwP4NtEPce+UtLv2NHHfqsW6xSxjWqsJkMdJ9afzu1jvn9M6e0j\r\n"
        + "MOTmPUCYVCioXK59It8ngN8NLtwaPgfnBwcbABEBAAG0BWFsbGVuiQE5BBMBAgAj\r\n"
        + "BQJgNQO9AhsDBwsJCAcDAgEGFQgCCQoLBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQxzGJxIrjAlxq\r\n"
        + "aggAgoiO82MZZMHyhZ3uLD4qTQ2vsT6+onhCr83kw0eFNM5AH0r3xlVARXHaViWC\r\n"
        + "SFutpb/34lrCTpJfLfKwdFU2bJP2SI3hAujtTg45UFklswu6GZaqQno6JKkZM4hw\r\n"
        + "ltFIXU1dMpIud7nsJ2QU46TI97n+HeD7DvOSGY/CFPnNot0YFHxXCKtHdPHk8JO3\r\n"
        + "JdOG0X90Yi9XSI1USv8HL/WjOTvhSqo7Qps2MpcUZrfNsa0H9Adk9xVYiz0nKNPY\r\n"
        + "qLQxFAiHb34vdav4e28anJ8th93SfiRn5OFK2G6R3DlhLlvn3h1dSAT6vSOrzx80\r\n"
        + "EylyMg2BIbRfp+JEgwCMf2V8X7kBDQRgNQO9AQgA3qV0wYvdH5M4XBzVwDtuGuIs\r\n"
        + "+GRcSRQqmvnt94e8ZE4Kv2w2Pf/JxPMwnPC92lVRypdOjmTZrT3R0z7g+D8mU5A9\r\n"
        + "o/CPvvSShA8Jh3z69S+hLP0nSaajsVsQlBGrI8ehI1EVJDsNh15PZrl27OK0aBb4\r\n"
        + "Fp0BYm0D2HaLnQPD4/jhTR13i1mt5E5hmBwiZiiWr/Wa1i1g1o/XaT4CApu91zgg\r\n"
        + "cmJBz9DL/C2hYC5lkp/cz5IJYp5BsvfA2lwamca33aHxFj8+Bz3+REWa8zvEqQ9U\r\n"
        + "a26RbPVjkeGChwNWLxNTuj1rNDdqB/KZO6iM02orqW86L45SKTBWYqPcpD7GeQAR\r\n"
        + "AQABiQEfBBgBAgAJBQJgNQO9AhsMAAoJEMcxicSK4wJcOLEIAMevvOk9iZ13T3yA\r\n"
        + "+ZW8mWKKE5aXy93VPKAvplP/WlW2VVGeb+6rEkFFsdN4doYIJPEIr+U7K0GDR6XX\r\n"
        + "TKLyI7BtUZPegOdjgcFWVGFnFogDnkrO+IPY+JUy1VMg8fGStThfa2dYEgd7yqpq\r\n"
        + "fZ97q5RQun1B+wyRdPDgC39roSGEwtXbRCZnuSMVNT7J9a2qnXkenvQRSoPjY7wQ\r\n"
        + "tn1wUfnHyjyS9OzfXTSHDi2A5JDRCh5L/V7Q93/P5Isv/U4QzIWudGM6AjuaoZ6i\r\n"
        + "chksRI9EchNKnSut9ebTyTkIJ80sB7Eyfp8TtORAnz8/Xf8A8aYD73r9rD4poSmo\r\n" + "FV15pP8=\r\n" + "=Yc74\r\n"
        + "-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----";

    try {
      PGPPublicKey key = getPublicKey(publicKey);
      System.out.println(encrypt("Test".getBytes(), key));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PGPException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help.

UPDATE #1: After getting the stacktrace, I found out that the error is due to an invalid provider which I then change using

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
```

So I had to change all reference to the provider.

```
private static String encrypt(byte[] data, PGPPublicKey encryptionKey) {
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    String step = "Step-0";
    try {
        step = "Step-1";
        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_256)
                .setWithIntegrityPacket(true)
                .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
                .setProvider(provider));
        
        step = "Step-2";
        encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encryptionKey)
                .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider(provider));

        step = "Step-3";
        ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        step = "Step-4";
        // create an indefinite length encrypted stream
        OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(encOut, new byte[1 << 16]);
        step = "Step-5";
        // write out the literal data
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream pOut = lData.open(cOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE, data.length,
                new Date());
        pOut.write(data);
        pOut.close();
        // finish the encryption
        cOut.close();
        step = "Step-6";
        
        return new String(encOut.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //throw new Exception(String.format("%s: %s", e.getMessage(), step));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String("");
}
```

But now I'm getting a different error.

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception creating cipher

    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
    at pgp.PgpImpl.encrypt(PgpImpl.java:85)
    at pgp.PgpImpl.main(PgpImpl.java:217)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: invalid key: Illegal key size
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder$MyPGPDataEncryptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1034)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1367)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1301)
    ... 6 more
```

UPDATE#2: Did a bit of research and came across [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Illegal-key-size-Error-when-using-PGP). Followed the instructions there and got everything working.

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: @tgdavies Done. Thanks.

Comment: When you throw a new exception as you do in  `throw new Exception(String.format("%s: %s", e.getMessage(), step));` you *must* include the original exception as the `cause` of the new exception you are throwing. Otherwise you are losing necessary context. Please fix that and add the complete stacktfrace.

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry about that. Done as suggested. I am now getting a more informative error thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your modified code works for me: (I have taken out the exception handling, but that should make no difference)

```
package pgp;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.KeyFingerPrintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPDataEncryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.jcajce.JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection;

public class PgpImpl {

    public PgpImpl() {
    }

    private static String encrypt(byte[] data, PGPPublicKey encryptionKey) throws PGPException, IOException {
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        String step = "Step-0";
        step = "Step-1";
        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_256)
                        .setWithIntegrityPacket(true)
                        .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
                        .setProvider(provider));

        step = "Step-2";
        encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encryptionKey)
                .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider(provider));

        step = "Step-3";
        ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        step = "Step-4";
        // create an indefinite length encrypted stream
        OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(encOut, new byte[1 << 16]);
        step = "Step-5";
        // write out the literal data
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream pOut = lData.open(cOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE, data.length,
                new Date());
        pOut.write(data);
        pOut.close();
        // finish the encryption
        cOut.close();
        step = "Step-6";

        return new String(encOut.toByteArray());
    }

    private static PGPPublicKey getPublicKey(String keyAscii) throws IOException, PGPException, Exception {
        InputStream encodedKey = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyAscii.getBytes());
        InputStream decodedKey = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(encodedKey);

        JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new JcaPGPPublicKeyRingCollection(decodedKey);
        decodedKey.close();

        PGPPublicKey key = null;
        Iterator<PGPPublicKeyRing> rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings();
        while (key == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
            PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = rIt.next();
            Iterator<PGPPublicKey> kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();

            while (key == null && kIt.hasNext()) {
                PGPPublicKey k = kIt.next();

                if (k.isEncryptionKey()) {
                    key = k;
                }
            }
        }
        if (key == null) {
            throw new Exception("Can't find key");
        }
        return key;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String publicKey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\r\n" + "Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)\r\n"
                           + "\r\n" + "mQENBGA1A70BCADK8BnH6GgMbnS1TJSpJvgH+D9VIw0sN8XZWQsUmWWV9WSqhqXt\r\n"
                           + "5wNC4XJDcaWtMCapaekQXV5S52T7QCxAz/E5oZzIDe+IUCHQz0WUs37S4Wnw+SZ6\r\n"
                           + "QNPXOFaC4nNByRq6gvg0+wtD2Bo/3OJur3f0O0aRSHNiwfd0PdFgG0NU5vGV9PwE\r\n"
                           + "xbTMpGssWexIC0MwJaYfJkxzov33CkwLaITvBTCn/J3oeX6JarMkgpurp1FAW0Jk\r\n"
                           + "YzgGMOOxwuEVedwP4NtEPce+UtLv2NHHfqsW6xSxjWqsJkMdJ9afzu1jvn9M6e0j\r\n"
                           + "MOTmPUCYVCioXK59It8ngN8NLtwaPgfnBwcbABEBAAG0BWFsbGVuiQE5BBMBAgAj\r\n"
                           + "BQJgNQO9AhsDBwsJCAcDAgEGFQgCCQoLBBYCAwECHgECF4AACgkQxzGJxIrjAlxq\r\n"
                           + "aggAgoiO82MZZMHyhZ3uLD4qTQ2vsT6+onhCr83kw0eFNM5AH0r3xlVARXHaViWC\r\n"
                           + "SFutpb/34lrCTpJfLfKwdFU2bJP2SI3hAujtTg45UFklswu6GZaqQno6JKkZM4hw\r\n"
                           + "ltFIXU1dMpIud7nsJ2QU46TI97n+HeD7DvOSGY/CFPnNot0YFHxXCKtHdPHk8JO3\r\n"
                           + "JdOG0X90Yi9XSI1USv8HL/WjOTvhSqo7Qps2MpcUZrfNsa0H9Adk9xVYiz0nKNPY\r\n"
                           + "qLQxFAiHb34vdav4e28anJ8th93SfiRn5OFK2G6R3DlhLlvn3h1dSAT6vSOrzx80\r\n"
                           + "EylyMg2BIbRfp+JEgwCMf2V8X7kBDQRgNQO9AQgA3qV0wYvdH5M4XBzVwDtuGuIs\r\n"
                           + "+GRcSRQqmvnt94e8ZE4Kv2w2Pf/JxPMwnPC92lVRypdOjmTZrT3R0z7g+D8mU5A9\r\n"
                           + "o/CPvvSShA8Jh3z69S+hLP0nSaajsVsQlBGrI8ehI1EVJDsNh15PZrl27OK0aBb4\r\n"
                           + "Fp0BYm0D2HaLnQPD4/jhTR13i1mt5E5hmBwiZiiWr/Wa1i1g1o/XaT4CApu91zgg\r\n"
                           + "cmJBz9DL/C2hYC5lkp/cz5IJYp5BsvfA2lwamca33aHxFj8+Bz3+REWa8zvEqQ9U\r\n"
                           + "a26RbPVjkeGChwNWLxNTuj1rNDdqB/KZO6iM02orqW86L45SKTBWYqPcpD7GeQAR\r\n"
                           + "AQABiQEfBBgBAgAJBQJgNQO9AhsMAAoJEMcxicSK4wJcOLEIAMevvOk9iZ13T3yA\r\n"
                           + "+ZW8mWKKE5aXy93VPKAvplP/WlW2VVGeb+6rEkFFsdN4doYIJPEIr+U7K0GDR6XX\r\n"
                           + "TKLyI7BtUZPegOdjgcFWVGFnFogDnkrO+IPY+JUy1VMg8fGStThfa2dYEgd7yqpq\r\n"
                           + "fZ97q5RQun1B+wyRdPDgC39roSGEwtXbRCZnuSMVNT7J9a2qnXkenvQRSoPjY7wQ\r\n"
                           + "tn1wUfnHyjyS9OzfXTSHDi2A5JDRCh5L/V7Q93/P5Isv/U4QzIWudGM6AjuaoZ6i\r\n"
                           + "chksRI9EchNKnSut9ebTyTkIJ80sB7Eyfp8TtORAnz8/Xf8A8aYD73r9rD4poSmo\r\n" + "FV15pP8=\r\n" +
                           "=Yc74\r\n"
                           + "-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----";

        PGPPublicKey key = getPublicKey(publicKey);
        System.out.println(encrypt("Test".getBytes(), key));
    }
}
```

My pom.xml has:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can you run that code and see what happens locally?

Comment: Apparently I had to download and install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from Oracle website [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html]. Just followed the instruction there and everything went well after.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BC

For the above error which you were getting first, add below line of code at the starting

Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).